# Move row back and forth between tabs when a cell is edited

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a lending library for books with one sheet to show what is currently borrowed (on sheet Borrowed). Every other sheet is someone's name (called Name in my example), showing what they own that can be borrowed. I want to copy the row to the Borrowed sheet when "Borrowed" is in column C, and when it is changed back to "Returned" from either Borrowed or Name, remove it from the Borrowed sheet. So they need to be linked somehow. I had tried using query= before but couldn't edit the status of the book on Borrowed, it would just break the row.

This code is working to get the row copied over to Borrowed, but I'm not sure how to accomplish the returned part.

```
    function onEdit(event) {
// source data in sheet named Name
// target sheet named Borrowed
// test column with yes/no is col 3 or C
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Name" && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == "Borrowed") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Borrowed");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1,1,numColumns);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);

}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hybrid approach, which uses spreadsheet functions in one direction (from Master sheet to Borrowed), and a script to move things in the opposite direction.

The Borrowed sheet contains the formula

```
=iferror(filter({row(Master!A:C), Master!A:C}, Master!C:C = "Borrowed"), "No books are borrowed at present")
```

This displays the records of borrowed books (assumed to be in columns A:C), preceded by the row number of each book in the master sheet. The row number helps in linking the records between sheets. (As a side effect, the data in Borrowed sheet moves to the right by one column).

If book status is changed to Returned from Master sheet, it goes away from Borrowed automatically. The tricky part is dealing with the edits to Borrowed sheet. This is what this script is for.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var entry = (typeof e.value == 'object' ? '' : e.value.toLowerCase());
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Borrowed' && col == 4 && entry == 'returned') {
    e.range.clear();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var originalRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
    ss.getSheetByName('Master').getRange(originalRow, 3).setValue('Returned');
  }
}
```

The script checks that the user indeed put "Returned" (case insensitive) in column 4 (D) of sheet Borrowed. If so, it notes the row number and *clears the edited cell*.  This restores the functionality of `filter` function, returning the sheet to its previous state. The script then reads the original row number from column A of Borrowed, and edits the appropriate cell of Master sheet. As a result of this edit, the Borrowed sheet no longer has the row with the returned book.

Yes, this is a somewhat roundabout way to do things... but it works.